# How to find the total length of a column value that has multiple values in different rows for another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, summary

Is there a way to find IDs that have both Apple and Strawberry, and then find the total length? and IDs that has only Apple, and IDS that has only Strawberry?

df:

```
        ID           Fruit
0       ABC          Apple        <-ABC has Apple and Strawberry
1       ABC          Strawberry   <-ABC has Apple and Strawberry
2       EFG          Apple        <-EFG has Apple only
3       XYZ          Apple        <-XYZ has Apple and Strawberry
4       XYZ          Strawberry   <-XYZ has Apple and Strawberry 
5       CDF          Strawberry   <-CDF has Strawberry
6       AAA          Apple        <-AAA has Apple only
```

Desired output:

```
Length of IDs that has Apple and Strawberry: 2
Length of IDs that has Apple only: 2
Length of IDs that has Strawberry: 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Find the total length of _what_?

Comment: What is expected output if change `EFG` to `ABC` ? then group `ABC` match or not?

Comment: I updated the desired output

Comment: What if an `ID` has fruit other than `Apple` and `Strawberry`? What should be the output when an `ID` has fruits `Apple`, `Strawberry` and some other fruits in the same group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If always all values are only `Apple` or `Strawberry` in column `Fruit` you can compare sets per groups and then count `ID` by `sum` of `True`s values:

```
v = ['Apple','Strawberry']
out = df.groupby('ID')['Fruit'].apply(lambda x: set(x) == set(v)).sum()
print (out)
2
```

EDIT: If there is many values:

```
s = df.groupby('ID')['Fruit'].agg(frozenset).value_counts()
print (s)
{Apple}                2
{Strawberry, Apple}    2
{Strawberry}           1
Name: Fruit, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael! I can just change ```v``` to apple or strawberry if I want to find the total length of total IDs for 1 fruit?

Comment: @Mick - yop, only need `set(x) == set(v)`

Comment: @Mick - If always all values are only `Apple` or `Strawberry` in column `Fruit`

Comment: What happens if I use ```set(x) == set(v)```?

Comment: @Mick - Also working if change order `v = ['Strawberry', 'Apple']` working same like `v = ['Apple','Strawberry']`, because sets has not defined ordering

Comment: If you have 10 different fruits this method will be very inefficient.

Comment: @MykolaZotko - thanks for feddback. Give me a sec for solution

Comment: @jezrael - the edit portion should be .agg(frozenset) - this allows set objects to be immutable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pivot_table` and `value_counts` for DataFrames (Pandas 1.1.0.):

```
df.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='Fruit', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)\
.value_counts()
```

Output:

```
Apple  Strawberry
1      1             2
       0             2
0      1             1
```

Alternatively you can use:

```
df.groupby(['ID', 'Fruit']).size().unstack('Fruit', fill_value=0)\
.value_counts()
```