# How to find the total length of a column value that has multiple values in different rows for another column BY LOCATION

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

This is **part 2** question of the [original problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64495124/how-to-find-the-total-length-of-a-column-value-that-has-multiple-values-in-diffe).

Is there a way to find IDs that have both Apple and Strawberry, and then find the total length? and IDs that has only Apple, and IDS that has only Strawberry? **BASED ON LOCATION**

df:

```
        ID           Fruit        Location
0       ABC          Apple        NY            <-ABC has Apple and Strawberry
1       ABC          Strawberry   NY            <-ABC has Apple and Strawberry
2       EFG          Apple        LA            <-EFG has Apple only
3       XYZ          Apple        HOUSTON       <-XYZ has Apple and Strawberry
4       XYZ          Strawberry   HOUSTON       <-XYZ has Apple and Strawberry 
5       CDF          Strawberry   BOSTON        <-CDF has Strawberry
6       AAA          Apple        CHICAGO       <-AAA has Apple only
```

Desired output:

```
IDs that has Apple and Strawberry:
NY       1
HOUSTON  1
IDs that has Apple only:
LA       1
CHICAGO  1
IDs that has Strawberry only:
BOSTON   1
```

The previous code was:

```
v = ['Apple','Strawberry']
out = df.groupby('ID')['Fruit'].apply(lambda x: set(x) == set(v)).sum()
print(out)
>>> 2
```

I tried the following but it did not work and gave me the same results

```
v = ['Apple','Strawberry']
out = df.groupby('ID', 'LOCATION')['Fruit'].apply(lambda x: set(x) == set(v)).sum()
print(out)
>>> 2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inefficient solution using `groupby` and `apply`

```
x = df.groupby('ID').agg({ 'Fruit': lambda x: tuple(x), 'Location': 'first'})
y=x.groupby('Fruit')['Location'].value_counts()
```

---

**y:**

```
Fruit                Location
(Apple,)             CHICAGO     1
                     LA          1
(Apple, Strawberry)  HOUSTON     1
                     NY          1
(Strawberry,)        BOSTON      1
Name: Location, dtype: int64
```

---

```
for index in set(y.index.get_level_values(0)):
    if len(index)==2:
        print(f"IDs that has {index[0]} and {index[1]}:")
        print(y.loc[index].to_string())
    else:
        print(f"IDs that has {index[0]} only:")
        print(y.loc[index].to_string())
```

---

```
IDs that has Apple only:
Location
CHICAGO    1
LA         1
IDs that has Apple and Strawberry:
Location
HOUSTON    1
NY         1
IDs that has Strawberry only:
Location
BOSTON    1
```